# Nunit not calling setup once per text fixture

Tags: c#, automated-tests, nunit

I'm new to Nunit and am trying to run 2 Test Fixtures, *A & B*. Within each Fixture I have a unique Setup method for each. However, when I click "Run All" in the "Test Explorer" in Visual Studio, the test setup for Fixture A is called (it was executed first) and Setup for Fixture B is ignored. I also get the same behavior when running all tests via command line. Below is my code:

Fixture A

```
[TestFixture]
public class A
{      
        [SetUp]
        public void SetupTest()
        {
            // ...Setup for Fixture A
        }                

        [Test, Order(1)]
        public void TestForFixtureA()
        {
            // ...perform test
        }
}
```

Fixture B

```
[TestFixture]
public class B
{      
        [SetUp]
        public void SetupTest()
        {
            // ...Setup for Fixture B
        }                

        [Test]
        public void TestForFixtureB()
        {
            // ...perform test
        }
}
```

What is the correct way to get Setup methods to execute per Fixture?

Comment: What happens when you only execute `TestForFixtureB` without `A`?

Comment: It runs correctly and vice versa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the incorrect attribute for setup at the test fixture level. The attribute you should be using is `[SetUpFixture]`. Information about this can be found in [the nunit documentation](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SetUpFixture-Attribute)

Here is a list of all the setup attributes and their usages taken from [the documentation](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SetUp-and-TearDown):

- **SetUpAttribute** is now used exclusively for per-test setup.
- **TearDownAttribute** is now used exclusively for per-test teardown.
- **OneTimeSetUpAttribute** is used for one-time setup per test-run. If you
  run n tests, this event will only occur once.
- **OneTimeTearDownAttribute** is used for one-time teardown per test-run.
  If you run n tests, this event will only occur once
- **SetUpFixtureAttribute** continues to be used as at before, but with
  changed method attributes.

This doesn't seem to explain the bizzare behaviour you are seeing, as setup should be ran per-test, but using the correct attributes couldn't hurt.

Comment: I changed my attribute for the `SetupTest()` to be `[OneTimeSetUp]` and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: The statement about `SetUpFixture` is incorrect. A `SetUpFixture` is a class without anu tests that performs setup for a __group__ of fixtures. It doesn't apply here. In addition, `OneTimeSetUp` applies if the intention is that the setup method only run once per fixture - that isn't stated in the question.

Answer (score 3):

If you intend your setup to be run once per fixture, use `[OneTimeSetUp]`. But if you intend it to run once per test within the fixture, then `[SetUp]` is correct. We can't tell what you intend from the code.

Whichever one you use, the setups should all run. The only situation in which `[OneTimeSetUp]` will run but `[SetUp]` will not is when no individual tests are found within the fixture. Are all the tests being recognized?

I suggest you verify very clearly that the setup is not being run. The easiest way is to temporarily create some output from the setup method.

Comment: OneTimeSetup was my intention. Thank you for clarifying.